# Java get HTTP property

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, encryption

I need to write a new JAVA program from a PHP old version.

In PHP they used **HTTP_SSL_PROTOCOL** to get TLSv1 or TLSv1.2 and **HTTP_SSL_CIPHER** to get AES128-SHA or other .. to get info of the client.

```
    private function getInfos() {
    // Récupération du protocole
    if(isset($_SERVER) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_SSL_PROTOCOL'])) {
        $this->protocol = $_SERVER['HTTP_SSL_PROTOCOL'];
    }

    // Récupération du Cipher
    if(isset($_SERVER) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_SSL_CIPHER'])) {
        $this->cipher = $_SERVER['HTTP_SSL_CIPHER'];
    }
}
```

In JAVA with Tomcat I'm not able to get it on my **HttpServletRequest**, I check Tomcat help but didn't find anything :( I try to get it from HTTP header didn't get anything.

Thanks

Comment: You are writing Java server code? Like servlet? Then SSL is taken care automatically. If you are writing Java client, then you can post some of the code.

Comment: If you still need to know the info just for logging, etc., you can maybe mention why you need that info.

Comment: I write a JAVA server with servlet. Its for a bank and I need to know who use TLSv1 to contact them and tell that he need to use TLSv1.2, same with Cipher.

Comment: Apparently it wasn't possible: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41813852/1364747 But there is some discussion about workarounds.